# Mac Terminal search and move files not containing pattern in name

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I use a program to rip radio music. Sadly one can not set the temporary folder apart from the folder where the finished mp3's end up later. So I cannot set the output folder to auto add to iTunes.

I'm alright in coding java and what not but have no experience with shell scripts.

I need a script that iterates through all the files within a folder like every 10 minutes and moves them to a different location if they don't start with the string "Track". All temp files are called "Track..." so it should only move finished ones then. Could anyone give me a help getting started?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script. You should set the DESTINATION directory properly before uncommenting the line which moves the files. Otherwise, you may end up moving them somewhere undesirable.

In the terminal, cd to the location where you save the snippet below and run the following commands to execute.

**Prep work:**

- cd /save/location
- chmod +x file_mover.sh # makes the file executable

**Schedule a job:**

- crontab -e
- */10 * * * * /path/to/file_mover.sh
- crontab -l # view list of scheduled jobs

With some minor tweaks you can make this accept CLI options.

```
#!/bin/bash 


# files to skip
REGEX='^TRACK'

# location to move the files
DESTINATION=/tmp/mydir

# directory to read from 
# PWD is the working directory
TARGET=${PWD}

# make the directory(ies) if it doesn't exists
if [ ! -f ${DESTINATION} ]; then
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION}
fi

# get the collection of files in the 
for FILE in $( ls ${TARGET} )
do
    # if the current file does not begin with TRACK, move it
    if [[ ! ${FILE} =~ ${REGEX} ]]; then

        echo ${FILE}

        # SET THE DESTINATION DIRECTORY BEFORE UNCOMMENTING THE LINE BELOW

        # if [ -f ${FILE} ]; then # uncomment if you want to 
        # ensure it's a file and not a directory     
              # mv ${FILE} ${DESTINATION} # move the file 
        # fi # uncomment to ensure it's a file (end if)
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the crontab with `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`*/10 * * * * shopt -s extglob; mv ~/Music/Temp/!(Track)*.mp3 ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Automatically\ Add\ to\ iTunes.localized/`

`shopt -s extglob` adds support for `!()`. See `/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html`.

Comment: Strong recommendation: put the script into a file in `$HOME/bin` (say it is `autoimportmp3`), and then run that script from `crontab`.  Keep the entries in the crontab short and simple (`*/10 * * * * $HOME/bin/autoimportmp3`); put the hard work into the script which it runs.